# How to generate pem file from create-key-pair command in windows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I running this command to create key-pair in aws:

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name MyKeyPair
```

The command is works. but no pem file is generate. [In the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-key-pair.html) there is no reference for how to do that.

After I run the command I get the pem content file in json structure to the console.

```
{                                                                                                        
    "KeyMaterial": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEpAIBAAKCAfe6quq7f2ikhT+wRV5pNzk9u3jqr3N
ta1tqaSoC3K5Tv4ZKeeT0WljQaNIQKV\nyg8WF8XtLKQS9PZ0mpPdkQbP7KSprwYusQTa0xldX8u423djFru36YQ71PDA6HdJl0r8h7RQ
sNKaXpStKq7\nHu4EzjHyQUVE9ffzDLwDMjNutAcm4bFhiNYGl9Twn+V0Jfq5wnnWluCG/sqMU6i/bWvb18iJ7dW2\n9Dl4czoSYp+kXB
/dT18bLWYlcOl9tNpBAECgYEA6dIIag6IFoSAP5/PstHk3IzT0YJ9sldRl7i/OJYsoaGs\nmoBtUgjjkvLWaEgV7pmeCGbmDPxmKtlKJf
ksMw+0NNivRnbhOeSBj1OwJCr67Uz0Mwr1AyhnkNlLWmD4dN1\npRQDy93l5/D0/l4A1muZWLVVboWvvg+KU0GVzx9WnIcXAStJGP4S3x
FDnZTl0ay8+dll3uN7Sm3/3qmDAor\nwSwsvUaOJy2dslDIZ+yaRQKBgQDL5/y/ORBlB4bgpxZ81CFZyM+536qr26Cp7YHBZYidpa/OXY
nD3R+Fgqs\nrig796uvJy9bsnBqrW9DDjeFDw6dnFU81MUNbjf4Fx5mPKoFcwSSxd7QaPePKCv+9RAZcWF3QeVa\nMtdNM0BemepdhHJ2
    "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",                                                                              
    "KeyFingerprint": "16:0b:c4:40:1e:e1:89:6a:75:d0:e1:aa:1a:92:38"                      
}
```

How to have pem file after running this command in **windows**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name <name> --query "KeyMaterial" --output text > key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the content of the key material info file, for example call it key.ppk and then use puttygen to convert the key

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html#putty-private-key

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--query` and `--output` options. It's described in detail in the docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-keypairs.html